# Why are "not bounded" operators not everywhere defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces, $\mathcal{D}(T)$ a subspace of $X$, and $T\colon X\to  Y$ a linear map. Such a $T$ is commonly called an *unbounded linear operator*, where *unbounded* just means that the domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is possibly a strict subspace of $X$.

I am confused by all the general questions flying around this definition and ask for some clarification. Is there a general argument why we consider such operators which are not defined on the whole space? In other words, I am interested in the following statement:

**Statement.** $\mathcal{D}(T)=X$ $\Rightarrow$ $T$ is bounded, or equivalently, $T$ is not bounded $\Rightarrow$ $\mathcal{D}(T)\neq X$.

In this context it might be interesting to look at the closed graph theorem: And operator defined on all of $X$ is bounded if and only if it is closed. Therefore it makes sense to ask whether there exist operators defined on all of $X$ which are not bounded.

There are many specific cases when this definition comes in handy. For example, differential operators are often first defined on a small class of functions (e.g. compactly supported, smooth functions) and can then be extended to larger domains. But here I am really considering *any* spaces and operators.

Of course, it would be interesting to know whether and how this changes when we restrict $X, Y$ to be Hilbert spaces.

Comment: For example, self adjoint operators are closed (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/260987/why-is-every-selfadjoint-operator-closed). One often wants to consider self adjoint, but unbounded operators, so one has to accept the fact that they are not defined on the whole space.

Comment: This is an argument of the "specific" type: Certain operators cannot be defined on the whole space, therefore we define them only on a subspace. But my question is whether a not bounded (i.e. not continuous) operator can or cannot be defined on the whole space.

Comment: "where *unbounded* just means that the domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is possibly a strict subspace of $X$." No, _unbounded_ means not (or "not necessarily") continuous.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Does my answer solve your question?

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes, it does. It seems there is no "general" argument of the kind I was looking for.

Comment: John von Neumann initiated the study of closed operators when he was studying Quantum Mechanics, and found that a lot could be said, including the existence of adjoint, provided the operator was also densely-defined. Without a closed (or closable) graph, it's tough to say much about the operator. As pointed out by others, closed + everywhere-defined on a Banach space requires boundedness, which is out of the question for important classes of operators such as differential operators, including those of Quantum Mechanics; but these are often closable (definitely if symmetric on Hilbert space.)

Comment: In short, there do exist everywhere defined, unbounded operators, but they're not good for anything.  They are awful pathological axiom-of-choice monsters and they don't correspond in any reasonable way to any natural operations.  Natural operations (multiplication, differentiation, etc) start out defined on a subspace of the Hilbert space, and there is no *natural* way to extend them to the entire space.  The Zorn's lemma arguments basically choose an extension *arbitrarily*, which prevents it from having any particular meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always define an unbounded operator on the whole space $X$, as long as $X$ is infinite dimensional.

Simply take any unbounded linear functional $\varphi : X \to \Bbb{K}$ (with $\Bbb{K} \in \{\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C}\}$) and some $x_0 \in X \setminus \{0\}$ and define $T : X \to X, x \mapsto \varphi(x) \cdot x_0$.

For the existence of $\varphi$, see [On every infinite-dimensional Banach space there exists a discontinuous linear functional.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288075/on-every-infinite-dimensional-banach-space-there-exists-a-discontinuous-linear-f)